# Zeta Function of a Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In general, is there a simple way of computing the zeta function of a curve (or variety) over $\mathbb{F}_q$? Here $q$ is an odd prime power. I've seen a nice computation for both affine and projective n-spaces over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Also, why are we interested in the zeta function of a curve (of variety)? What does it actually tell us about the original object?

Comment: Have you looked at the Weil conjectures?

Comment: You may find these lecture notes interesting: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/lecture3.pdf.  Have you read Silverman's book on elliptic curves?  It contains a section on zeta functions.